# Facing issues while uploading file in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload

I am working on uploading files in JAVA app. Everything is good but I don't know where it is saving uploaded file on the server side.

```
**servlet code**
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
int byteRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
totalBytesRead += byteRead;
}
String file = new String(dataBytes);
String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
out.println(saveFile);
int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
int pos;
pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();

%><Br><table border="2"><tr><td><b>You have successfully upload the file by the name of:</b>
<% out.println(saveFile);%></td></tr></table>
<%
Connection connection = null;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.112:3306/file";;;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
FileInputStream fis;
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
File f = new File(saveFile);
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into file(file_data) values(?)");
fis = new FileInputStream(f);
psmnt.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int)(f.length()));
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
if(s>0) {
System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
}
else {
System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload file.");
}
}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
%>
```

It shows success message on the screen but I am not sure whether it is actually uploading file or not. If YES, where it is storing file. any help!

Comment: You are opening a mysql connection, writing into a table and asking where does it write?

Comment: it just saving the file name. i just don't know the directory where it is putting the file. @MustafaGenç

Comment: Why are you using scriptlets?

Comment: Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, use a library that handles file uploading, like Apache Commons File Upload.